# Taylor polynomial approximation - Interval of convergence

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Find the Taylor polynomial of order $n$ of the cosine function around $x=0$. Then find the largest interval in which the sequence of polynomials $\{p_n\}$ converges to $f(x) = \cos(x)$.

I am having trouble doing the second part (the interval) and could not find much content in the books that I know to help me.

Comment: Perhaps the formula for the error would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The Taylor series converges for every number $x$, but because of the periodicity and the symmetry, only the interval $[0,\pi]$ is needed.

Comment: See the cauchy-hadamard-theorem.

Comment: why it converges for every number x? Should I analyze the rest limit of rest(reminder) function?

Comment: Ok, why does it converges to cosine function? I know the theorem.

Comment: Additionally, all derivates are bounded. This is enough to ensure, that the taylor series really converges towards the function.

Comment: A tiny correction: The remainder must tend to 0, which is also the case here.

Comment: Ok, but it will tend to zero for all x at the domain. In general, we can find an inderval I that it does tends to zero. Doesn't it shows that it converges to the function for all x?

Comment: There is a nice counterexapmle for that : Let f(x)=exp(-1/x^2) for all nonzero x and 0 for 0. Then the taylor series for f is just 0 because every derivate is 0 at the point 0, so the series converges nowhere (except for 0) to the function.

Comment: But such pathological cases are very rare indeed.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the example. In this case, can you explain again why the fact of the derivatives be bounded implies that the series convergers to cosine? I know that the series converges, but why to cosine.

Comment: Alas, no. I only have found this criterion, I cannot prove or explain it,sorry. In most books, it is simply stated that the remainder has to tend to 0, the counter example is mentioned rarely.